# Hard wrap string literals at print margin in Eclipse C/C++

Tags: c, eclipse, coding-style

C/C++ Eclipse can automatically format and wrap just about any kind of code and behaviour is very configurable, except for string literals. Here is a made up example where debug output message happens to be longer than what can fit within a printable area:

```c
if (some_kind_of_action() == TOUGH_LUCK) {
    system_debug_print("Task name error: some_kind_of_action() failed due to your sloppy design.");
}
```

Using 79 character print margin the desirable result could be:

```c
if (some_kind_of_action() == TOUGH_LUCK) {
    system_debug_print("Task name error: some_kind_of_action() failed due to yo"
        "ur sloppy design.");
}
```

You can do this manually by typing your string literal, then placing cursor at the desirable wrap point and pressing Enter key. Eclipse will automatically add necessary quotation marks. This is all nice, until something in your code changes and you have to manually redo the wrapping. I don't see why wrapping at print margin can't be done fully automatically like any other piece of code.

Is there any way to automate hard wrapping of string literals at print margin in Eclipse for C/C++?

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse does not support this feature in any of its editors (even though it was [requested](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=35779) nine years ago). However you may be able to avoid breaking your lines manually by using the following plugin for enabling soft wrap.

http://ahtik.com/blog/projects/eclipse-word-wrap/

Comment: thanks for your comment. I guess we are talking about slightly different things here. If I understood correctly, you are talking about "soft" wrap, which is only visual line wrap, which is not supported in Eclipse and is what this plugin does. I am talking about a "hard" wrap, which is mostly supported by Eclipse, except for strings. What a "hard" wrap does is it actually inserts line breaks into the text.

Comment: Sorry if i have been unclear. The bug report i link discusses both hard and soft wrap and eclipse supports neither. I provided the link to the soft wrap plugin just in case it would be helpful to you, even though it is not hard wrap.